# Accessing internal time-varying and fixed parameters in root function and event function in deSolve

Tags: r, desolve

I’m using R+desolve to model seaweed growth and wish to implement a function in which seaweed is harvested given a threshold value of an internal variable of the model (i.e. not a state variable so not accessed via the ‘y’ of (t, y, parms)). I would also like the threshold value to be controlled by a variable that I can pass to the model in parms.  Some (simplified) example code

```
Seaweed_model <- function(t, y, parms,...) {
  with(as.list(c(y, parms)), {

    #(lots of internal variables hidden here for brevity) 
    
   I_top<-PAR(t)*exp(-K_d*(z-h_MA))                                     # calculate incident irradiance at the top of the farm
    I_av <-(I_top/(K_d*z+N_f*a_cs))*(1-exp(-(K_d*z+N_f*a_cs)))          # calclulate the average irradiance throughout the height of the farm
    g_E <- I_av/((I_s)+I_av))                                                                          # light limitation scaling function

#(state variables not relevant to this problem omitted) 
    dN_f        <- mu_g_EQT*N_s-(d_m*N_f)                   # change in fixed nitrogen

    list(c(dNH4, dNO3,dN_s,dN_f,dD),
         g_E       = g_E,

        )
  })
}
```

Then I would like to trigger an event function when g_E reaches a threshold value

```
rootfunc  <- function(t,y,parms,...){
  return(g_E - threshold_value)  #how do I access these values from the ode solver call?
}
```

And the event

```
eventfunc <- function(t, y, parms,...){
  c(y[1:2],y[3]*harvest_fraction,y[4]*harvest_fraction,y[5]) #reduces biomass state variables fractionally
}
```

The harvest parameters are added in to the parms passed to the ode call

```
parms_harvest<-c(
  harvest_threshold=0.2,
  harvest_fraction=0.75
)

lim_harvest <- ode(times = times, func = Seaweed_model,  y = y0, parms = c(parms_porphyra,parms_farm,parms_harvest), events=list(func=eventfunc, root=TRUE),rootfun=rootfunc)
```

All of the examples for desolve events do a root evaluation on a state variable of the model (e.g. y[‘N_s’] is accessible in the example above) rather than internal variables of the model. g_E as written in the above rootfunc clearly will not work but I have no idea how to access it if it’s even possible.  Substituting  a state variable of the model for g_E (not useful scientifically but good for testing purposes) I get error: object ‘threshold_value’ not found so it doesn’t seem like the root function is able to access parms even.

I’m sure I’ve missed something fundamental here. Thanks so much in advance for you help!

Comment: It would be nice if you could make your example complete and reproducible. The best option is a simplified "toy model" that we can paste to an editor and run it. A few hints: (1) you cannot access internal variables in the root function. (2) the recommended approach is indeed to create a "technical state variable. (3) The root function can acces the parms, just use the `with` construction.

Comment: Thomas, many thanks for your reply. Also thanks to Karline Soetaert for some support via email. I have solved the internal variable problem by reclaculating the internal variable within the root function, using the state variable which controls it. And, as you point out, I was missing the ```with``` construction in the root and event functions, so problems solved! Seems obvious now...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You should also consider to answer your question yourself. This will help others who find your question in SO and you can probably earn a few reputation points.